Should I comment possible solutions in SG when the question can't be published yet
Should I comment some possible solutions in SG when the question is not yet complete (such as not including a minimal reproducible example)?
If I comment, my answer may be lost after the question is published, or if OP uses these solutions to solve the problem and no longer edits the question.
If not, I may forget it when re-evaluating.

Stack Overflow has pretty clear rules about what goes in comments and what doesn't. Unless specifically mentioned, we should not assume you can do things differently in the staging ground.

"my answer may be lost after the question is published" -Not really "lost", it's just harder to see/find. You can still get it via the post's activity timeline.

@nocomment that only works for people able to access Staging Ground (and, I assume, the asker?); people who don't meet the qualifications to review Staging Ground posts cannot get to that.

@RyanM Ah, didn't realize that's a "privilege" (in quotes because I find SG posts rather bothersome).

No.
The reviewer guidelines explicitly mention:

Give guidance, but don’t give the answer
Please resist the temptation to answer questions through comments or edits. If you know the answer and the question is ready, publishing it and answering the public question is the way to help expose the answer as widely as possible to help more folks in the future.

If a question can be answered from the information in the question, it is ok to publish (though you might want to edit and polish it a bit - make sure not to change the meaning of the author with that of course).
Special cases
Duplicate
If you are able to find a duplicate, even better. In that case, vote to close the question as a duplicate in the Staging Ground instead of approving. If you can't because you already voted for a wrong duplicate (and the post is in "New" "Re-Evaluate" after "Major Changes" i.e. it is not currently closed), you could ask someone in the Staging Ground Discussion/Support chatroom to do that for you.
No MCVE
If a question can be answered without a MCVE, it probably doesn't need one. A special case is when the MCVE is provided in the comments. In that case, you can either edit the example into the question (if you can answer it, you probably know enough to be able to edit that comment in properly) or you ask the author to do that and use the "Requires Major Changes" option.
After the question is published, you can start writing on an (ideally high-quality) answer.
Unsure
Another special case was mentioned in the comments by the OP:

how about when I think (most of these kind of) the problem should be solved this way, but given information is not enough to determine that

In this case, please ask the author for the information needed for answering the question.
generally answerable but still unsure
If you think a question is probably answerable by another subject matter expert but you have an idea of what the solution could be, remember that Perfect is the enemy of good. Approve the question (possibly with a polishing edit) and then you can still answer/comment.
Typo
If it's a typo or otherwise trivial issue that would be convered by the typo/not reproducible flag and you are sure this is the solution, write a comment about it and close the question as typo/not reproducible.
If it's a typo or otherwise trivial issue that would be convered by the typo/not reproducible flag and you are unsure, I guess you could ask about that issue (or whatever is needed for explaining it but that's kinda unnecessary in most cases in my opinion) and use the "Requires Major Changes" option.
If it is the case and the author doesn't Re-Evaluate, the question stays in the Staging Ground like that and you have prevented a question from getting published and closed.
If it is the case and the author Re-Evaluates (confirming it's a typo), you can vote to close it.
If it is actually not a typo, re-review it and choose the appropriate option.

Thanks for your answer. And how about when I think (most of these kind of) the problem should be solved this way, but given information is not enough to determine that

@typed-sigterm if you think the information in the question is insufficient to answer it, then post a comment to that effect and request major changes.

Specifically, I would post a comment asking for the necessary details. I'll edit my answer for that.

What's a "possible solution"?
If you've seen something many times before and know it's a duplicate (even though it's also unsuitable for other reasons, such as not having a proper MRE: let's say you managed to spot where the bug occurred in a code dump) then vote as duplicate, and feel free to use a comment to explain why it's a duplicate - point at the appropriate line of code and describe how it matches the problem pattern in the (hopefully canonical) Q&A.
If you think you may know an answer but you aren't sure because of an issue with the question (in particular, missing information), don't guess, even with qualification - hold back your guess, and request the missing information etc.
If you want OP to try something because it will help diagnose the problem, then do comment for that - even if that could lead to the problem being trivially solved. In the cases where that does lead to a trivial solution, one may say that the question was caused by a typo anyway.
But if you want OP to try something because you think it might answer the question, but you also don't think the question should be published yet - what really is your basis for thinking it might be an answer?
In all cases, remember that a question published on the site is for everyone, not just OP. The goal of SG evaluation is not to fill out a "support ticket"; it's to determine whether the question is suitable for the site. Whether OP actually fixes the problem is a separate matter. But at the same time, within the SG you are interacting directly with OP and the question is shielded from public consumption. Make sure not to mislead OP about what Stack Overflow is or how it works; but also try not to leave a bad impression.

"it's to determine whether the question is suitable for the site." - I disagree. In my opinion, the SG is mainly for getting questions to a state that are suitable for the site, blocking/filtering other questions is a great consequence of that.
